What causal inference method is suitable to identify the effect of different components of a webpage on the decision to purchase?
I am getting started with causal inference for a project where I want to evaluate the causal effect of different components of a webpage on users' decision to purchase. For illustration purposes, let's pretend I want to do that for Airbnb listings.
I want to measure the effect of a feature on the user's decision once the user is on the listing page (to be independent of the ranking of the listing in the search). The changes of interest can be a price change, the addition of pictures, a new capability such as a dedicated workspace to the listing, possibility of free cancellation, etc.
The causal diagram can be seen below.
I measure the number of purchases in the month following the change. I would take the values of the relevant variables displayed in that graph at the time of the change.
The question I have is the following:
variables like rating and number of reviews are likely to vary over the measurement period causing a cyclic dependency (highlighted in orange).
How should I handle this - should I change the measurement period to be one were ratings and number of reviews are constant ? (therefore changing the target variable to be (number of purchases) / (measurement time period) ?)

